# Indentation problem

Tags: indentation, parindent

For a lexicon I am working on, I created the following command: `\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\newline \setlength{\parindent}{10pt}\indent{\footnotesize{• #1} \textit{#2}}}`. It works perfectly, but if the definition is more than one line long, the resulting paragraph shows the first line indented (as in the second bullet definition of the pic).
[image]

I would like the entire paragraph to be 10pt indented, so that the lines following the first do not stick out on the left side.
Does anyone can help? Thank you!!

EDIT
Here a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
    
    
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{microtype}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{4mm}
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
        
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
        \setmainfont{Antinoou}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newcommand{\entry}[4]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\noindent \textcolor{cyan}{#1} \ {#2} \ \emph{#3} \ {#4} \\} 
                                    % #1 = lemma; #2 = dialetto del lemma; #3 = \definizione; #4 = varianti dialettali
        \newcommand{\abb}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}
        \newcommand{\paradigm}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
            \newcommand{\stat}[1]{{#1}\textsuperscript{†}} %per le forme stative del verbo
    \newcommand{\nota}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % note di utilizzo
    \newcommand{\occurrence}[1]{\textnormal {#1}} %passo o papiro in cui compare il termine

    \newenvironment{derivlist}{\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nosep,
         label=\hspace*{10pt}{\footnotesize •},leftmargin=*]}%
         {\end{itemize}\leavevmode}
    \newcommand{\derivitem}[2]{\item {\footnotesize #1} \textit{#2}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}

    \section{Ϣ ϣ}
        \entry{ϣⲁⲩ \paradigm{ϣⲟⲩ-}}{SB}{\abb{n. m.} uso, valore; \nota{come aggettivo} utile, buono, adatto.}{}
        \entry{ϣⲛⲏ}{SAF}{\abb{n. f.} giardino.}{}
        \entry{ϣⲱⲛⲉ \paradigm{\stat{ϣⲟⲟⲛⲉ}}}{SA}{\abb{v. intr.} essere malato, essere debole.}{\begin{derivlist}\derivitem{ⲡ-ⲉⲧ-ϣⲱⲛⲉ}{colui che è malato, infermo.}\derivitem{ⲡⲁ-ⲛ-ⲉⲧ-ϣⲱⲛⲉ}{colui che appartiene ai malati, infermiere \occurrence{O.BawitFribourg 47}}\end{derivlist}}
\section{Ϭ ϭ}
    \entry{ϭⲁⲙⲟⲩⲗ}{SABF}{\abb{n. m. e f.} cammello.}{\begin{derivlist}\derivitem{ⲙⲁⲛ|ϭⲁⲙⲟⲩⲗ}{cammelliere.}\end{derivlist}} 
    \entry{ϭⲟⲟⲩⲛⲉ}{S}{\abb{n. f.} sacco \nota{(anche come unità di misura)}.}{}
    \entry{ϭⲣⲟ(ⲟ)ϭ}{S}{\abb{n. m.} seme.}{\begin{derivlist}\derivitem{ϣⲟⲩ|ϭⲣⲟϭ}{buona semenza \occurrence{O.BawitFribourg 55}.}\end{derivlist}}

    \end{multicols}{2}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The vertical space around the `derivlist`s is caused by the `parskip` package; I don't quite understand why you set `parskip` to 4mm, and then later add that package, which changes it again. What do you actually want `\parskip` to be? Do you want that space between the `\entry`s (in cyan) consistently, or no space at all? Consider putting `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` at the start of this list of entries (and reset it when the list is over) and change `\\ ` at the end of the definition of entry to `\par`.

Comment: Also since it appears that `#4` in `\entry` is optional, you might consider using `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newcommand` and make it an optional parameter, perhaps even building the `derivlist` stuff right into its definition. Finally, though this is unrelated, consider using interword spaces after the period in the `\abb` commands, e.g., `\abb{n.\ e.\ m.\ f.}` to avoid intersentence spaces there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to recreate an itemize environment. Just use a customized itemize environment.

```
\usepackage{enumitem} % in preamble
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,
    label=\hspace*{10pt}{\footnotesize •},leftmargin=*]
    \item {\footnotesize #1} \textit{#2} 
\end{itemize}}
```

EDIT: If you're going to have multiple `\deriv`s in a row, however, it may be better to put them in the same itemize environment, like this:

```
% in preamble
\usepackage{enumitem} % in preamble
\newenvironment{derivlist}{\begin{itemize}[nolistsep,
    label=\hspace*{10pt}{\footnotesize •},leftmargin=*]}%
    {\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\derivitem}[2]{\item {\footnotesize #1} \textit{#2}}

% in body
\begin{derivlist}
    \derivitem{Something}{Stuff here.}
    \derivitem{Something else}{More stuff here.}
\end{derivlist}
```

You may also want to read the [enumitem package](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) documentation for more details on how to use it to control spacing in enumerate and itemize environments.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't thought of a customized itemize environment (my LaTeX skills are still way basic). By the way, if the page is not fully filled, the space between an item and the following is quite large. Is there a way to control this behavior and print the seme line spacing of the non-itemized paragraph?

Comment: If you're going to have multiple `deriv`s in a row, it's probably best to put them in the same itemize environment with multiple `\item` calls. I'll elaborate by editing my answer. But if that doesn't solve your problem, there are probably other ways, but I want to know more about your document class and other settings with a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. I won't bother you more, unless necessary. I will try to understand the documentation on enumitem and implement what I need on my own. Thank you so much for the support!

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the space before and after the `derivlist` environment? I'm trying with `nosep` or `topsep=0pt` but it doesn't seem to work.

`\newenvironment{derivlist}{\begin{itemize}[nolistsep, nosep, label=\hspace*{10pt}{\footnotesize •},leftmargin=*]}%
    {\end{itemize}}`

Comment: There is no space above or below for me when I test. You must be using different settings elsewhere, but I don't even know what document class you're using. I would need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to be able to help.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question in order to add a MWE. Thank you for your precious help.